# Celery consumer does not receive messages from SQS queue on LocalStack

Tags: python, pip, celery, amazon-sqs, localstack

I have a SQS queue on a LocalStack server and I'm trying to consume messages from it with a Celery consumer.

It seams that the consumer is properly attached to the queue, for example the queue `sqs-test-queue`, but it does not receive any message when I try to send one with `aws` command.

My `celeryconfig.py` looks like this:

```
from kombu import (
    Exchange,
    Queue
)


broker_transport_options = {'region': REGION}
broker_transport = 'sqs'

accept_content = ['application/json']
result_serializer = 'json'
content_encoding = 'utf-8'
task_serializer = 'json'

worker_enable_remote_control = False
worker_send_task_events = False
result_backend = None

task_queues = (
    Queue('sqs-test-queue', exchange=Exchange(''), routing_key='sqs-test-queue'),
)
```

and my `tasks.py` module looks like this:

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu.utils.url import quote


AWS_ACCESS_KEY = quote("AWS_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_SECRET_KEY = quote("AWS_SECRET_KEY")
LOCALSTACK = "<IP>:<PORT>"

broker_url = "sqs://{access}:{secret}@{host}".format(access=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                                                     secret=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
                                                     host=LOCALSTACK)

app = Celery('tasks', broker=broker_url, backend=None)
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')


@app.task(bind=True, name='tasks.consume', acks_late=True, ignore_result=True)
def consume(self, msg):
    # DO SOMETHING WITH THE RECEIVED MESSAGE
    return True
```

Tried to execute it with `celery -A tasks worker -l INFO -Q sqs-test-queue` and everything seams OK:

```
...

[tasks]
  . tasks.consume

[... INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqs://AWS_ACCESS_KEY:**@<IP>:<PORT>// 
[... INFO/MainProcess] celery@local ready
```

but when I try to send a message with `aws sqs send-message --endpoint-url=http://<IP>:<PORT> --queue-url=http://localhost:<PORT>/queue/sqs-test-queue --message-body="Test message"`, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed something in the configuration maybe?

**PS:** If I try to run the command `aws sqs receive-message --endpoint-url=http://<IP>:<PORT> --queue-url=http://localhost:<PORT>/queue/sqs-test-queue`, I'm able to get the message.

**NOTE:**

I'm using `Python 3.7.0` and my `pip freeze` looks like this:

```
boto3==1.10.16
botocore==1.13.16
celery==4.3.0
kombu==4.6.6
pycurl==7.43.0.3
...
```

Comment: how do u consume the sqs message. Whatever code that is within the consume method is not being executed. Do I need to call another task?

Answer (score 3):

I am going through the same thing as you. To fix it I did a couple of things:

- I set the `HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL` and `HOSTNAME` env variables in localstack
- Set `broker_url` to `sqs://{access}:{secret}@{host}:{port}` (as you have it)
- Make sure that the celery worker's `broker_transport_options` does not include the config item: `wait_time_seconds` since this causes errors with localstack as of February 7th, 2020 ([check issue here](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/2030)).

Once I did those two things, it started working, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! `HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL` is the culprit if you are running localstack with docker-compose.

Quote from the docs:
`HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL`: Name of the host to expose the services externally 
(default: localhost). This host is used, e.g., when returning queue URLs 
from the SQS service to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Celery can't publish or consume arbitrary messages to/from *any* message queue system. Use kombu for that - that is what Celery uses behind the scenes too.